# Splitting a list/vector of special character in R

Tags: r, split

Lets say I want to split `x <- 1:100` into 10 different chunks, I can easily do it with
`split(x, sort(x%%10)` since `x` is an integer.

What if I wan to split `y` into 3 chunks, where `y <- 1_1, 1_2, ... 1_n, 2_1, 2_2, ... 2_n, 3_1, 3_2, ...3_n` where `n` = 100.

The first chunk is from `1_1, 1_2, ... 1_n`.

The second chunk is from `2_1, 2_2, ... 2_n`

The third chunk is from `3_1, 3_2, ...3_n`

I tried the similar approach as `x`, but I got error message of `In Ops.factor(holding, 10) : ‘%%’ not meaningful for factors`. I'm suspecting the underscore symbol is the culprit here.

Can anyone guide me through this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do this with:

```
split(y,gsub("_\\d+$","",y))
```

Here we create a `factor` using `gsub("_\\d+$","",y)`, which extracts the first digit preceding the `"_"` from `y`. To illustrate, suppose `y` is:

```
y <- c("1_1","1_2","1_11","1_100","2_1","2_2","2_11","2_100","3_1","3_2","3_11","3_100")
split(y,gsub("_\\d+$","",y))
##$`1`
##[1] "1_1"   "1_2"   "1_11"  "1_100"
##
##$`2`
##[1] "2_1"   "2_2"   "2_11"  "2_100"
##
##$`3`
##[1] "3_1"   "3_2"   "3_11"  "3_100"
```